# References on Economics of Vouchers

Tags: reference-request, education-economics

I am interested in key references on the economics of vouchers. In particular I am interested in asking, "Under what conditions are vouchers more or less useful?"

Tangentially related resources of a high quality are also welcome.

The kinds of references which I am looking for:

1. Papers and books
2. Informal works (eg a YouTube recording of a good talk)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An overview of vouchers that is a bit outdated but a good place to start building an understanding of past work:

http://www.nber.org/papers/w7092

---

On school vouchers:

https://www.aeaweb.org/articles?id=10.1257/aer.97.3.789

http://faculty.smu.edu/millimet/classes/eco7321/papers/rouse.pdf

https://www.aeaweb.org/articles?id=10.1257/aer.96.3.847

https://www.aeaweb.org/articles?id=10.1257/aer.90.1.130

https://jswinton.gcsu.edu/ECON%203640/Expenditure/voucher%20potential.pdf

---

housing vouchers:

https://www.aeaweb.org/articles?id=10.1257/000282804322970788

https://www.aeaweb.org/articles?id=10.1257/pol.20130064

https://economics.nd.edu/assets/153486/carr_jillian_jmp.pdf

http://www.nber.org/mtopublic/482.pdf

^^^ Those are a few of the papers I've read over the last two years involving vouchers.